# how to accept input from user in Junit console

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3

I am trying to write Junit test case for the function given below:

```
class A{
  int i;
  void set()
  {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    i=in.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Now my problem is when i create a Junit test case for it, it does not except input from user:

```
 public void testSet() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("set");
    A instance = new A();
    int i=1;
    instance.set(i);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    //fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

Please suggets what should i do to accept input from user.

Comment: i have tagged junit aswell tomake it more appropriate .. :)

Comment: You don't need input from user in JUnit tests. If you need to test with some `InputStream`, attach it to your `OutputStream` and feed input programmatically.

Comment: @VictorSorokin Can u pls illustrate by an example?

Comment: Really, you should design your code so that any code under test doesn't need to read from `System.in`, but instead reads from a passed-in `InputStream` or the like.

Comment: i know but that's my requirement..is there no way to enter input from user ...and test the method using Junit

Comment: The purpose of using JUnit is for performing automated tests. IMO, what you are trying to achieve is against that purpose. You should be creating some test-fixtures instead.

Comment: but i really need to test a method which takes input from user...is there no way by which i can achieve this?

Comment: While @Victor's suggestion is the best option for your need, data could be fed into testcases through the DataProviders of TestNG. And porting testcases from JUnit to TestNG requires very little effort.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`System.setIn()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29) to mock user input:

```
String inputData = "user input data";
System.setIn(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(inputData.getBytes()));
```

Now if you call your `set()` method it will read the data from your string rather than from standard input.